# Use regex to change <uc>text</uc> to TEXT

Tags: c#, regex

I need to convert the below title using regex to new title, where `<uc></uc>` markup identifies text to be converted to upper case

Title - "`this <uc>faq</uc> deals with <uc>sp</uc`>"

New Title - "`This FAQ deals with SP`"

Comment: Is this HTML or your own markup? If it's HTML, perhaps you'd prefer to use [CSS' text-transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)?

Comment: Not HTML but c# code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the following C# code

```
string s = @"this <uc>faq</uc> deals with <uc>sp</uc>"; 
string result = Regex.Replace(s, "<uc>(.*?)</uc>", m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper());
```

That will match the the beginning and end of your markup but lazily so that it doesn't match more than one.  It captures the part you want to keep then it will take the match and pull out the value of the capture and upper case it.  Additionally you could include `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` if you need to match stuff like `"<UC>something</UC>"` as well.

Note: that this will not handle nesting like `"<uc>some<uc>stuff</uc></uc>"` but I'm assuming that you don't need to deal with anything like that.